# Where is SDL.P (Point constructor) defined?

Tags: haskell, sdl-2

I've attempted to comb [the repository](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2) (oh the joys of globally used single character names) without luck, but maybe I'm looking for the wrong things.

Seeing documentation for SDL.P would probably also work.

For future reference, is there a good way to go about finding data constructors in Haskell (as they seem to be difficult to grep for in the single-character case)?

Comment: Load/import the re-exporting module in ghci and run ":i P" ?

Comment: I now realize I had actually found it, and that my error was that I had forgotten how `newtype` worked - still, all of these answers and comments have been useful.

Answer (score 4):

Hackage has haddocks for the sdl2 package. If you click the "Index" link, then click "P", you can find a list of all identifiers that start with that letter -- including the P data type.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.4.1.0/docs/doc-index-P.html

Answer (score 3):

Is this it? It’s all I could find using stackage search within the “sdl2” package.
https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.13/sdl2-2.4.1.0/SDL-Internal-Vect.html#v:P

Edit, how I did it:

You can limit the search offered by Stackage to a single package, using the URL: https://www.stackage.org/package/PACKAGE_NAME, so in this case https://www.stackage.org/package/sdl2.

Searching for operators, put them in parentheses, such as "(.)".  For your question, search for "P" like so: https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.13/hoogle?q=P&package=sdl2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21138674)

Comment: Thank you!  Good advice.  Would you comment also apply to the answer from @Daniel Wagner?

Comment: This answer would be a bit more useful if you explained how to search within a specific package. Otherwise, this does seem to answer the question since it was indeed just asking for a link.